# Removing Seed node from Datastax datacenter

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-php-driver

I have 6 nodes in our data center of which 3 node also act as seed nodes.I was planning to remove 3 nodes from rack2 and also reduce seed node count to two. With "nodetool decommission" we can remove nodes but is there any extra steps involve in removing seed nodes.

```
UN  10.10.1.56  339.96 MiB  1            ?         rack1
UN  10.10.1.46  334.72 MiB  1            ?         rack1
UN  10.10.2.76  307.72 MiB  1            ?         rack2
UN  10.10.2.66  296.15 MiB  1            ?         rack2
UN  10.10.2.86  316.89 MiB  1            ?         rack2
UN  10.10.1.36  375.69 MiB  1            ?         rack1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update seed list on nodes before decomissioning seed node - change list, optionally do the rolling restart one node at time, or in the new versions use `nodetool reloadseeds`